# How to keep something shown while hovering over a div? (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, image, hover, viewer

I'm having trouble with jQuery. Please have a [look at this page](http://tehwebz.com/site/). I've created a sliding image viewer which when hovered over shows a div with the class "paging". The problem I'm having is I want the div to be shown when hovering over it as well, as it now doesn't.
This is the javascipt which makes the div appear: (I removed two irrelevant lines from this code)

```
$(".image_reel a").hover(
function() {
    $(".paging").fadeIn('fast');
}, function() {
    $(".paging").fadeOut('fast');
});
```

Any ideas? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to clear the animation queue to avoid the "blinking"

http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/

Comment: Know where I have to put it? Thanks! :)

Comment: $(".image_reel a").hover(
function() {
    $(".paging").clearQueue().fadeIn('fast');
}, function() {
    $(".paging").clearQueue().fadeOut('fast');
});

Comment: Sorry, when you hover over "paging" it disappears and fades back in again.

Comment: Yupp. I'm not using it on fadeIn because then nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
$(".image_reel").hover(/*...*/);
```

that should work if the .paging is inside the .image_reel